# Receiving an error when moving table from one server to the other

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to move a Wordpress table from my old server to my new one and I am receiving this error:
SQL query:

```
--
-- Database: `username_film`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `wp_commentmeta`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_commentmeta` (
`meta_id` bigint( 20 ) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`comment_id` bigint( 20 ) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`meta_key` varchar( 255 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
`meta_value` longtext,
PRIMARY KEY ( `meta_id` ) ,
KEY `comment_id` ( `comment_id` ) ,
KEY `meta_key` ( `meta_key` ) ,
KEY `disqus_dupecheck` ( `meta_key` , `meta_value` ( 11 ) )
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT =1277;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1046 - No database selected
```

So, on my old server, I went into phpmyadmin and exported the wordpress table (not the entire server database) in SQL format, then went into my new server and uploaded it through import. What am I doing wrong? Please note that I am not very experienced with database administration so details in answers would be very helpful!

Comment: You have to create and/or use a specific database where this table is supposed to be imported.

Comment: That is very correct, I realised my mistake minutes after I posted this. Feel free to make this an Answer and I will mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create and/or use a specific database where this table is supposed to be imported!

Comment: Tack sa mycket!

Comment: I thought that might be rude.. It's actually Thanks very much in Swedish :P